# PyCharmの検索用入力フォームで日本語フォントが表示されません。対応方法を教えてください。

Tags: python, 文字化け, pycharm

## 環境

#### PyCharmのversion

```
PyCharm 2019.1.3 (Community Edition)
Build #PC-191.7479.30, built on May 30, 2019
JRE: 11.0.2+9-b159.60 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 4.15.0-47-generic
```

#### OS

Xubuntu 18.04

```
$  cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS"
```

## 現象

PyCharmのTooltipや検索用入力フォーム内で、日本語を入力すると、下図のように四角で表示されます。

ただし平仮名の「の」は表示されます。

#### 検索用入力フォーム

「あのね」と入力。

[image: PyCharmの検索用入力フォーム]

#### Tooltip

`hoge`メソッドのdocstringは「あのね」
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

## PyCharmの設定

#### Appearance & Behavior -> Appearance

Use custom font: `Droid Sans Mono`

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### Editor -> General -> Font

Font: `DejaVu Sans Mono`
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

## 質問

対応方法を教えていただきたいです。
たぶん日本語フォントがないため、日本語が四角で表示されているのだと思います。

また、以下の現象が発生しているのはなぜでしょうか？

- xfce4-terminalでフォントを`DejaVu Sans Mono`にしても、日本語は表示された。
- 平仮名の「の」は表示される

## 追記

日本語が含まれている「Noto Sans CJK JP Regular」フォントを設定しましが、解決しませんでした。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 完全にエスパーですが、「の」だけ表示されるのは数学用に「の」だけ収録しているフォントを使っているのかもしれません。　https://togetter.com/li/848185

Comment: 確実に日本語が表示されるフォントを指定（し、エディタを再起動）するとどうなりますか？

Comment: 確認してみます。「確実に日本語が表示されるフォント」はどのように調べればよいでしょうか？

Comment: 一旦[Google Noto Fonts](https://www.google.com/get/noto/#sans-jpan)からNoto Sans CJK JPをインストールしてみるというのはいかがでしょうか。プログラミング向きのフォントではありませんが、日本語は確実に収録されているフォントです。

Comment: Noto Sans CJK JP Regularを使いましたが、解決しませんでした（質問文に追記しました）。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PyCharmをどのようにインストールされているか(tar.gzのアーカイブだとかJetBrains Toolsboxだとかそれ以外だとか)で多少の違いがある気がするのですが、とりあえずtar.gzでDL、展開しただけのものと仮定して条件を近付け試してみました。

[image: 文字化け時]
まず、こちらが文字化けしている状態。たしかに質問にあるとおりです。

この事象は当該のUIパーツがPyCharmにバンドルされているjreによってレンダリングあたりが起因するよう。ArchWikiに[文字化けの修正](https://wiki.archlinux.jp/index.php/Java_%E5%AE%9F%E8%A1%8C%E7%92%B0%E5%A2%83%E3%81%AE%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88#.E6.96.87.E5.AD.97.E5.8C.96.E3.81.91.E3.81.AE.E4.BF.AE.E6.AD.A3_.28JRE8.29)という項目があるのですが、まさにこれと同じものです。

つまり、バンドルされているJREにフォールバックフォントを設定することで解決できます。

バンドルJREのフォントはPyCharm内の`/jre64/lib/fonts`以下に配置されています。つまり、たとえば

```
mkdir (PyCharmのインストールディレクトリ)/jre64/lib/fonts/fallback/
ln -s '/usr/share/fonts/opentype/noto/NotoSansCJK-Light.ttc' (PyCharmのインストールディレクトリ)/jre64/lib/fonts/fallback/
```

のようにfallbackフォントとしてシンボリックリンクを張ってやることでPyCharmがこれを参照,表示可能になります。

[image]

他にもましな解決策があるかもしれませんが、一度お試しください。

Comment: >PyCharmをどのようにインストールされているか
以下のサイトからtar.gzをダウンロードしてインストールしました。
https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=linux

Comment: ありがとうございます。解決できました。

Comment: @hinaloe こちらの方法は、フォールバックフォントを登録しているので、「の」だけは元のフォントで表示されているという理解で間違ってないでしょうか？

Comment: 「の」の存在すっかり忘れてました、見た感じこの手順では確かに元のフォントで表示されているようですね…